# Djcelery forces the use of 'database' backend, how to properly bypass it?

Tags: django, redis, celery, djcelery

In my Django project, I use no SQL database at all, my primary datastore is MongoDB, through [mongoengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/django.html).

I want to setup Celery to work with Redis as the broker and backend. I installed [django-celery-with-redis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery-with-redis/), installed Redis (locally and in production), and tried to use the following in my settings.py:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = BROKER_URL
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

But when I ran the celery process and it received a task to process, when returning the result, it complained with errors that settings.DATABASES was improperly configured. That didn't make much sense since I set CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND to be Redis.

I discovered that djcelery overrides the backend on `djcelery.setup_loader()` to `database`: see DjangoLoader from the [source code](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/loaders.py#L38).

I struggled to find ways to bypass DjangoLoader's overriding, and the only way I found was by making a duplicate of [djcelery/loaders.py](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/loaders.py) and modifying that line:

```
override_backends = {
    'database': 'celery.backends.redis.RedisBackend',
}
```

Then in my settings.py I do:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = BROKER_URL
os.environ.setdefault('CELERY_LOADER',
    'myproject.utils.ugly_djcelery_hack.DjangoLoader')
```

Notice no `djcelery.setup_loader()` there any more.

**This is clearly an ugly hack, is there a more elegant way of doing this?**

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just set `redis` as `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND`? See [the docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#task-result-backend-settings) for reference.

`django-celery` overrides default `celery.backends.database` for a good reason: you simply can't use `SQLAlchemy` with `Django ORM`. I see no point in routing a `database` backend to `redis`.

Comment: I've tried `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis'`, with same effects. The recommended way to set this variable is actually the whole Redis URL, see [the docs again](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#redis-backend-settings). Could you explain more about about your second paragraph? As far as I know SQLAlchemy is not involved here.

Comment: I've pointed you to docs exactly for that purpose -- not having to describe how to configure the backend. It's not only recommended way, it is the only way.

Furthermore, normally `celery.backends.database` is a `SQLAlchemy` backend. All `django-celery` does is replace it with `Django ORM` based backend. Again, see the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#conf-database-result-backend). There is a link to `SQLAlchemy` documentation regarding connection links.

Comment: Now I understand your point, and yes I agree routing `database` backend to `redis` is bad (IMO ugly hack). I think the issue here is actually that the DjangoLoader in djcelery/loaders.py doesn't yet see the settings.py variables. In [DjangoLoader.read_configuration](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/loaders.py#L60) it tries to get the settings attribute, and I have checked with a print statement that it is `None`. So the problem is how to make the loader get the configurations from settings.py.

Comment: Did you try introspecting what `settings` contain while `read_configuration` is executed? If it does contain other constants defined, then it's weird. If it doesn't contain your configuration – focus on solving that.

Comment: I did debugged (`pdb`) inside `read_configuration` and it isn't loading other constants, it uses Django default values. Solving that has been tough. FYI, I use a hierarchy of settings files: common.py as a base, then development.py and production.py that both do `from settings.common import *`. This has worked fine for several months. I tried placing the CELERY_ constants in common.py or development.py, same effects. I'm starting to wonder that the Celery loader is being executed before the settings file is available.

Comment: Ok, seems to be some kind of circular import problem, caused by some startup functions I have in the settings file. This is not the first time I struggle with the lack of a proper space for initialization code in Django.

Comment: The initialization code depends on some settings. So I see two options: (1) do this ugly hack above and leave the initialization code in the settings file(s); (2) remove the ugly hack, set djcelery as I should, remove initialization code that depends on settings. Option 2 is not feasible, I really need the initialization code, so I have to stick with option 1 unless there is some other option.